# Removing an image from a label at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, label, nullreferenceexception

In C#, I have a 2d array of labels who's image I want to change depending on conditions.  More specifically, I'd like to get it toggle between a given image and no image at all (turning it into a transparent label) and back again when conditions are met.  Currently, to wipe the label clear again, I'm using this:

`someLabelArray[i][j].Image = null;`

But it always throws a Null Reference Exception, which makes me suspect this isn't the 'right' way to do things. Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding the error? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please post code that you've *constructed* two-dim array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that would be absolutely fine - but that either `someLabelArray` is null, or `someLabelArray[i]` is null for whatever value of `i` you're using.

Simple way to test this: change your code to:

```
someLabelArray[i][j].Text = "foo";
```

which obviously has nothing to do with images, and will definitely work if your array is okay. I suspect this will fail in the same way, in which case you need to look carefully at how you're constructing your array.

If this *works* - well, I'll have another look then :)

Comment: After reviewing it, you are absolutely right in that someLabelArray[i] was null for a given value.  Many thanks for getting me thinking on the right track.